# Powershell search for text in files

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a problem. I'm going to search files on my computer for keywords in the files. The keyword is for example "C:\Project".
I get error when running this script below. But when i'm deleting C:\ in the search string it's working. But i'm interested in to search with C:\ in the beginning. Can someone help me with correction in the script?

```
$path = 'D:\Cross'
$searchword = 'C:\Project'
$Filename = '*.config'

Get-ChildItem $path -Include "$Filename" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
  If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $searchword ){
    $PathArray += $_.FullName
  }
}

Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_}
```

Comment: Either add switch `-SimpleMatch` to the `Select-String` cmdlet or escape the backslash in the searchstring with another backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-String` defaults to *regular expressions*, so if you want a simple substring search instead, use the `-SimpleMatch` switch:

```
Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $searchword -SimpleMatch
```

or make sure you escape any regex metacharacters:

```
Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $([regex]::Escape($searchword))
```

---

You can also simplify your code significantly by using `Where-Object` and piping the file objects directly to `Select-String` instead of manually invoking `Get-Content`:

```
$filesWithKeyword = Get-ChildItem $path -Include "$Filename" -Recurse |Where-Object { $_ |Select-String -Pattern $searchword -SimpleMatch |Select-Object -First 1 }
```

`$filesWithKeyword` now contains all the `FileInfo` objects for which `Select-String` found at least 1 occurrence of the keyword in the corresponding file on disk. `Select-Object -First 1` ensure the pipeline aborts as soon as the first occurrence is found, preempting the need to read large files all the way to the end.

The whole script thus becomes:

```
$path = 'D:\Cross'
$searchword = 'C:\Project'
$Filename = '*.config'

$filesWithKeyword = Get-ChildItem $path -Include "$Filename" -Recurse |Where-Object { $_ |Select-String -Pattern $searchword -SimpleMatch |Select-Object -First 1 }

Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$filesWithKeyword.FullName
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for your reply. But I'm not getting it right. I'm not that good at PS. Can you write the lines in their context? The whole script. Then I would be grateful.

Comment: *Then* he would be grateful.

Comment: Gratification hereby provided ;-)

Comment: Almost instant gratification!